# MDX sum a previous month

Tags: sql, service, ssas, mdx, analysis

I have created a cube with many different aggregations and any summing I do is within MDX.  I am modeling lottery behavior based on previous drawings.  Here is my current code:

```
WITH 
    SET [Alpha And Beta And Theta] AS
        NONEMPTY (
            { [Dwtbl Dim Test Alpha].[Alpha PK].MEMBERS } *
            { [Dwtbl Dim Beta].[Beta PK].MEMBERS } *
            { [Dwtbl Dim Theta].[Theta PK].MEMBERS }    
        )
    MEMBER Measures.TotalHits AS
    SUM ( [Alpha And Beta And Theta]
      , COALESCEEMPTY([Measures].[Hits],0)
    )
    MEMBER [Measures].[PrevMonth_TotalHits] AS
        (ParallelPeriod ([Date].[CalendarYear].[Month NK]
           , 1
           , [Date].[CalendarYear].Currentmember
        )
       ,[Measures].[TotalHits]
      )
    SELECT              
        {
            [Measures].[TotalHits],
            [Measures].[PrevMonth_TotalHits]
        } ON COLUMNS
    FROM [cubAgents]
    WHERE ( [Date].[Year].[2013],
            [Date].[Month NK].[7])
```

Now, when I pass in July, the code works as expected; I get hit counts from July and June.  However, when I pass in August [8] which has not occurred yet, I get null for both current and previous month.

Why does this happen?  Well, my set [Alpha And Beta And Theta] is a big nonempty crossjoin, with each dimension not occurring since it is in the future.  If I remove the nonempty, it will work just fine ... but take 3 minutes to complete.  I have spent too much time on this and I guess it is time to reach out to the experts.

Perhaps one method would be to directly sum my [Hits] measures for a previous month as opposed to using parallelPeriod, something like

```
    MEMBER [Measures].[PrevMonth_Hits] AS
    SUM ( {[Alpha And Beta And Theta]*[Date].[CalendarYear].Currentmember.LAG(1)}
      , COALESCEEMPTY([Measures].[Hits],0)
    )
```

This doesn't work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!